# Regular Expression to get only words from file starting with letter and removing words with only numbers and punctuation in python

Tags: python, regex, nltk, regex-negation

I have a text file which i am reading in python through nltk functions.
I need to get only only words from file starting with letter and removing words with only numbers and punctuation.
For ex :-

```
['Osteama pranay@123  123 !']
```

so the desired output is

```
Osteama pranay@123
```

Please suggest a regular expression for this

Comment: I suggest you *write* a regular expression, or at least put *some* demonstrable effort in before asking others to do your work for you.

Comment: I did it lot of times...but i am not getting desired output

Comment: show us your efforts

Comment: [i for i in s if re.search(r'^[A-Za-z]', i)]

Comment: but its not giving me a desired output...this works good on lists...

Comment: When you add information, please, [edit] your question

Comment: Thanks...I am new to stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
' '.join(re.findall(r'\b[a-z][^\s]*\b', 'Osteama pranay@123  123 !', re.I))
```

the same regexp used with nltk.RegexpTokenizer

```
import nltk 
tokenizer = RegexpTokenizer(r'[a-zA-Z][^\s]*\b')
nltk.tokenize('Osteama pranay@123  123 !')
```

Comment: it does work but it dosent remove '.' operator though.Thanks

Comment: i will write a separate regex to remove full stops after every sentence...Thanks!

Comment: I have changed the regex to r'\b[a-z][^\s.]+'

Comment: still it gives me , comma character....also it doesent removes some standalone punctuation characters...

Comment: Can you read the regexp in the answer? If you don't like it, edit the character classes.

Comment: i didnt got you

Comment: i have eddited it again. It is hard to catch all the corner cases without detailed specification what you want.

Comment: it should remove standalone punctuation and numbers from file thats it..thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To use regular expression you need to >>>import re first

```
import nltk,re,pprint
from __future__ import division
from nltk import word_tokenize

def openbook(self,book):
    file = open(book)
    raw = file.read()
    tokens = nltk.wordpunct_tokenize(raw)
    text = nltk.Text(tokens)
    words = [w.lower() for w in text]
    vocab = sorted(set(words))
    return vocab
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    openbook(file(sys.argv[1]))
```

It might help you

Comment: it should keep punctuation and numbers occuring in letters...does it work ?